# Laravel 5.4 ajax POST request keeps responding with GET 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Hi all been working on this issue for a bit now and I'm trying to figure this out with no luck.

Basically I copied another working project with similar logic and the new copied version is the only one throwing this 405 header on ajax post.

**The console always converts my POST to GET on request**

```
GET http://app.local/en/pdf 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

This is what my `web.php` looks like

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]
    ],
    function()
    {
        /** ADD ALL LOCALIZED ROUTES INSIDE THIS GROUP **/
        Route::get('/', 'MainController@home');
        Route::post('pdf/', 'MainController@constructPDFOutput');
    });
```

and what my MainController looks like

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function constructPDFOutput(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

Here is what my js ajax post looking like

```
function getPDF() {
    $('#error-well').hide();
    var form = $('#generate-form');

    var data = {
        '_token': $('[name="_token"]').val(),
        'current_lang': USERLANG,
    }

    console.log(`Posting Data to server...`);
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'native',
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: data,
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function (blob) {
            console.log("works!)
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus)
        }
    });
}
```

and my form looks like this.

```
<form id="generate-form" method="POST" action="pdf">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your form action is `pdf`, but your route is in a group with a prefix `'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),`. Shouldn't you action be something like `en/pdf`?

Comment: Quick question: What is a "native" dataType? Looks to be non-standard based on the docs

Comment: @karl based on the console response, it appears to be attempting to use the correct URL

Comment: @MattFletcher which response? the `405 (Method Not Allowed)`? It mostly means that the route doesn't exist

Comment: @MattFletcher ah, I see what you mean, still, the point is valid, 405 mostly mean an error in the route.

Comment: Yes, route doesn't exist to laravel, because it's expecting a post request. Which makes me think it's an issue with the Ajax call syntax. But it's still attempting the correct language prefixed route, just using the wrong method

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon if I add another route with GET Route::get('pdf', 'MainController@constructPDFOutput'); I get my $request responded. So the link is there

Comment: There's also a missing double quote in the success handler, but I imagine that's just a typo on stack overflow, as it would probably throw up a whole syntax error

Comment: @MattFletcher that's my fault. Simplified my code for stackoverflow and added a quick console.log :)

Comment: Can you try and make the most basic `$.post()` request to that URL just to check where in the stack the issue lies?

Comment: Because my suspicions are that the issue lies in that Ajax config object, but if it's a server thing that doesn't something mental then that would help rule it out

Comment: @MattFletcher still get the 405 :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159623/discussion-between-baconjuice-and-matt-fletcher).

Comment: Glad you managed to sort it out. For anyone looking at the comments post chat, it was a typo in the laravel routes, with an accidental slash before the pdf route